# how to make new custom emotion Softkeyboard for Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-softkeyboard, emoji

What I want to make is emotion keyboard. When I searched, I found Emoji Layout is need to be very attractive.

In short, I want to make app which would be keyboard and that can be used anywhere in messenger.
I want develope android service like softkeyboard not application in android.
and how to do animation in emoji keyboard like this below image:-

[image]

Any idea how to go ahead to create Emoji Softkeyboard?

Comment: I have really appreciated your comments, I want to develop emoji keyboard(service) not app.

Comment: Any idea/ inputs how to go ahead to create **app** ... 4 minutes later : I want to develop emoji keyboard(service) **not app**. Nice. How can other people answer your question when you don't even know yourself what it is exactly that you want ?

Comment: Ohh Sorry , I want make emoji softkeyboard not an app.

Comment: So Please Help me regards this.